# In Python change a function name where function is dynamically created by types.FunctionType

Tags: python, python-3.x

I could dynamically create a function and ran it without a problem, but somehow the new function kept the original name.

This is my test code, test_copy_func2.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import types
from typing import Callable

def copy_func(f: Callable, name=None):
    fn = types.FunctionType(f.__code__, f.__globals__, 
                            name or f.__name__,f.__defaults__, f.__closure__)
    fn.__dict__.update(f.__dict__)
    return fn

def f1():
    pass

f2 = copy_func(f1, name="f2")

print(f"f1={f1}")
print(f"f2={f2}")
```

when I ran the script, I saw f1 and f2 are indeed two different functions by addresses. However, they have the same name "f1". why?

```
>test_copy_func2
f1=<function f1 at 0x00000208D43A1F28>
f2=<function f1 at 0x00000208D43AEF28>
```

(This was done on Windows 10 with Python 3.7.3)

This caused a problem when I tried to pickle f2. My original program was to copy a local function f1 to a global function f2; and then pickle f2, because pickle works only on global functions, not on local functions. But the above issue makes pickle fail to work on f2, because f2 points to f1.

How can I wipe out the trace of f1 from f2?

Comment: I'm away from my computer right now but I suspect `fn.__dict__.update(f.__dict__)` is the culprit

Comment: As an aside, please use the general [python] tag for all python related questions. Honestly, at this point python means python 3 anyway...

Comment: I commented out fn.__dict__.update(f.__dict__). it didn't help.

Comment: I even added fn.__name__ = "f2". it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: set "qualname" attribute

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import types
from typing import Callable

def copy_func(f: Callable, name=None):

    fn = types.FunctionType(f.__code__, f.__globals__,
                            name or f.__name__,f.__defaults__, f.__closure__)
    fn.__dict__.update(f.__dict__)
    fn.__qualname__ = 'f2'
    return fn

def f1():
    pass

f2 = copy_func(f1, name="f2")
print(f"f1={f1}")
print(f"f2={f2}")

print(f"f2.__code__={f2.__code__}")
```

the result is

```
>test_copy_func2.py
f1=<function f1 at 0x00000234A6E51F28>
f2=<function f2 at 0x00000234A6E5EF28>
f2.__code__=<code object f1 at 0x00000234A6B4B8A0, file "C:\Users\...\test_copy_func2.py", line 13>
```

You can f2 is indeed "function f2" now.

The only leftover "f1" is in f2.**code**. Not sure how to get rid of it, but yet.